# to sync published project list (by project server ) with a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server, sync

What is the best or most efficient way to sync a published project by project server with a SharePoint portal list ?

Beside [Nintex](https://community.nintex.com/community/build-your-own/nintex_gallery/blog/2016/03/10/creating-a-project-in-project-server-from-sharepoint-with-selected-project-type) work flow.

What I am looking for exactly is to use a list of projects (which are published in project server) in a look up list (or in similar lists).

I found a [timer job solution](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/how-to-create-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013/) but please, if it is possible recommend a no-code solution.

What is Microsoft standard solution? Is it good idea to use something like  [BCS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx)?(I think if we use BCS then it would be impossible to run a workflow)